# Problema no print do python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho 2 inputs que recebem o primeiro e o último nome de uma pessoa, depois é informado os valores digitados e é solicitado a idade da mesma, porém o print está mostrando as informações de nome entre "**Colchetes**". Como posso remover?

**Essa é a saída**

Type your first name: elvis
Type your last name: da silva
['Elvis'] ['Da', 'Silva'], Type your age: 18

**Esse é o código**

```python
first_name = str(input('Type your first name: ').split())
last_name = str(input('Type your last name: ').split())

age = int(input('{}, Type your age: '.format(str(first_name+" "+str(last_name)).title())))
```

Comment: Creio que você estava querendo usar o método `.strip()` para remover espaços antes e depois da _string_ e acabou se confundindo.

Answer (score 2):

O `split` é a causa do "problema", ao utiliza-lo voce converte a string para uma lista, veja um exemplo:

```
name = 'Foo'

print(type(name))
<class 'str'>

print(name)
Foo

name = name.split()
print(type(name))
<class 'list'>

print(name)
['Foo']

last_name = 'Bar'
last_name = str(last_name.split()) # O que vc esta fazendo

print(type(last_name))
<class 'str'>

print(last_name)
['Bar']
```

Voce poderia fazer de diversas formas, uma das mais simples seria:

```
first_name = input('Type your first name: ')
last_name = input('Type your last name: ')

age = int(input('{} {}, Type your age: '.format(first_name, last_name)))
```

Note que não há necessidade de usar `str()` no `input` pq ele já converte automáticamente para string.